# Proof of part of Bellman-Ford Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, bellman-ford

How can I prove this in the Bellman-Ford algorithm:

If there are no negative-weight cycles, then every shortest path from the source `s` to the sink `t` has at most `n-1` edges where `n` is the number of vertices in the graph.

Any ideas?

Comment: If graph has no cycles, that stament is trivially true. If there is a positive cycle, and your path uses that cycle, there must be at least 1 positive edge. You can remove it and get a shorter path with less distance. As the path with the cycle had at most n edges, this new path will have at most n - 1.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is unrelated to programming.

Comment: This question might be better suited for cs.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That statement verbatim is trivially false: in a graph where all edges have zero weight, there are no negative-weight cycles, but every path is the shortest.
What we can prove is the following slightly (but importantly) different version:

If there are no negative-weight cycles, then **there exists** a shortest path from the source `s` to the sink `t` which has at most `n - 1` edges, where `n` is the number of vertices in the graph.

---

Here is the proof.
Suppose there is a shortest path of `>= n` edges.
Then this path has `> n` vertices.
By pigeonhole principle, some two vertices are the same.
So we can remove a part of the path, transforming `s -> (sequence-1) -> v -> (sequence-2) -> v -> (sequence-3) -> t` into just `s -> (sequence-1) -> v -> (sequence-3) -> t`.
The length of the cycle `v -> (sequence-2) -> v` was nonnegative, so our new path is not worse than the old one.
And as the old one claimed to be the shortest, it can not be better too.
Together, these mean that we removed a cycle with zero weight.

The important thing is that the number of vertices decreased during our procedure since we removed at least one occurrence of `v`.
Now, repeat the above procedure until the path has less than `n` edges.
It is still a shortest path.
So, we proved that a shortest path with `< n` edges exists.